# Count the total tree structure

Tags: sql-server

I've got a table which contains object_id, object_name, derived_from_object_id

What function(s) do I need to look at to be able to provide a total count of derivations based on a provided object_id?

Example

```
1    object1    0  
2    object2    1  
3    object3    1  
4    object4    0  
5    object5    3  
6    object6    2  
7    object7    3  
8    object8    5
```

There is no defined maximum number of derivations from an object or the children. So if I wanted a total count from objectid 1 the result would be 7.

I've thought about writing a stored procedure which simply returned a count for each object id, it would then call itself for each id that there was a child for. Whilst I think this would work I think it's completely the wrong direction to go.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [recursive common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) to find all the derivations from a particular starting point.

#### Table and Data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.ObjectTree;

CREATE TABLE dbo.ObjectTree
(
    [object_id] integer NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [PK dbo.ObjectTree object_id]
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    [object_name] varchar(50) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [UQ dbo.ObjectTree object_name]
        UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED,
    derived_from_object_id integer NULL
        CONSTRAINT [FK object_id]
        FOREIGN KEY (derived_from_object_id)
        REFERENCES dbo.ObjectTree ([object_id]),

    INDEX [IX dbo.ObjectTree derived_from_object_id] (derived_from_object_id)
);

INSERT dbo.ObjectTree
    ([object_id], [object_name], derived_from_object_id)
VALUES
    (1, 'object1', NULL),  
    (2, 'object2', 1),  
    (3, 'object3', 1),  
    (4, 'object4', NULL),  
    (5, 'object5', 3),  
    (6, 'object6', 2),  
    (7, 'object7', 3),  
    (8, 'object8', 5);
```

#### Recursive Query

```
-- Where to start
DECLARE @ObjectID integer = 1;

WITH R AS
(
    -- Anchor
    SELECT
        OT.[object_id]
    FROM dbo.ObjectTree AS OT
    WHERE
        OT.[object_id] = @ObjectID

    UNION ALL

    -- Recursive
    SELECT
        OT.[object_id]
    FROM R
    JOIN dbo.ObjectTree AS OT
        ON OT.derived_from_object_id = R.[object_id]
) 
SELECT
    derivations = COUNT_BIG(*)
FROM R
OPTION MAXRECURSION(0);
```

This returns 7 for `[object_id] = 1`.

Try it at [[image: dbfiddle icon]**db<>fiddle**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ae9266b6cb8ae72b69972dc27c188d8e).

#### Using `MAXRECURSION`

The `MAXRECURSION` [query hint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-query) can be used to prevent a poorly formed recursive CTE from entering into an infinite loop. If that is a concern for you, use a suitable maximum recursion level instead of the zero (no limit) above. The default (no hint) is 100.